# How can I stop codelenses from breaking up indent guides in VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, user-presence, codelens

I have this visual annoyance when I am using VS Code. Whenever a method or class is declared, the "reference" counting is causing the vertical lines that connects the curly braces to break.

It is very annoying, I tried finding the settings in user preference but could not find anything. Could someone help me?

I find the "reference" count is alright, but how can I keep the vertical curly braces pair lines from breaking. I don't have this problem in Visual Studio.

[image: Picture Showing where the lines break]

Comment: Maybe you want to make the picture smaller and highlight the areas you want to focus on.

Comment: It is not clear what you want us to see in that image.

Comment: codelens lines do not have the indent lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and as far as I know, there's not much you can do about it for now except wait for it to get handled. If you google "`github vscode issues codelens indent guide`", you should easily find [Indent Guides Have Breaks Where CodeLens UI is Rendered #9604](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9604). There, you'll see that one of the maintainers, [@alexdima](https://github.com/alexdima) [commented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9604#issuecomment-240098460):

> Code lenses are implemented as view zones (same mechanism as embedded editors when you find all references or as the diff editor). In some of the view zones (such as code lens) it makes sense to render the indent guides inside view zones, while in others (such as the embedded editors or the diff editor) it does not, therefore marking this as both a feature request and a bug.

You can give that issue ticket a thumbs up reaction to show support for it getting prioritized (there's a big backlog), and subscribe to it to get notified about discussions and updates. [But please *don't* make noisy comments like "me too" / "+1" / "bump"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions).